# displaying web content in swift without an API

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

**Overview**

One of my friends wanted me to create an iOS application that displayed his web page, through something like *WKWebView*, and have a native menu for navigating to each page on his site.
Essentially, the purpose is to help out a friend and get a little better at iOS development at the same time. I realize that the best way to do this would be to setup an API, but my friend is unwilling to go through that extra work and would like it done this way.

**Challenges**

I started creating my application by creating adding a *WKWebView* to my view and loading website with multiple pages ( in this case, Google ). The setup looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var webKit: WKWebView = WKWebView()
@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    setConfiguration()
    webKit.load(myRequest)

}

func setConfiguration() {
    webKit.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webKit = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
    webKit.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
    view.addSubview(webKit)
}


}
```

As you would expect, It successfully loads the webpage. However, I am facing challenges figuring out how to load a new link to the WebView from something like a collapsable menu and/or *UITableView*.

**Question**

Is this feasible? Can i have something like a *UITableView* (with, lets say, a clickable link in each cell) achieve this purpose? If not, what would be the best way to tackle this issue, given the aforementioned terms.

Comment: How about making the URL a property of this view controller?  Then you would have each table view cell associated with a different URL and pass the chosen one to this controller when preparing for a segue. Put both the table controller and the web view controller inside a navigation controller.

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question, but if the goal is publishing the work product of this exercise to the App Store, you may have trouble getting it past review for violation of [4.2 Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality): "*Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.*"

Comment: @esqew Yeah, this is really just intended to be used by one person.

Comment: @PhillipMills I believe this is the solution to my issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Implement the WKNavigation delegate methods (set the navigation delegate on your WKWebView) and link up a couple of arrow buttons to goForward and goBack. On your tableview just store the strings for the URLs. On select, you'd load the web page.

You will also need these two methods to allow the navigation to work.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Lastly just add the following to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

BTW - You will want to move the URL to the Class scope and set it in a simple function that changes the URL with an argument. Make another separate function to load the page. Call as needed.